# Storyboard segue usages

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uistoryboardsegue

When a `UIView` is created using `storyboard` there are three methods available I would like to know more about: `custom`, `push`, and `modal`. Can someone please explain the purpose and usage of each?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[**Modal:**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2)

when you will use style type mode the new screen completely obscures the previous one. The user cannot interact with the underlying screen until they close the modal screen first.

[**Push**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2)

When you use push screen is presented on the navigation stack you can always press the back button to return to the previous screen.

[**Custom:**](http://blog.jimjh.com/a-short-tutorial-on-custom-storyboard-segues.html)

In custom you can define your own segue class, where you can define your own way for transition between the screen

I have linked tutorial also in this answer. check it for more details